# Можно ли поменять значения второго аргумента js?

Tags: javascript

Добрый день есть такая разметка

```
<button onclick="cart.add('8', '1')" class="button button-cart"><span>В корзину</span></button>


cart.add('8', '1')"
// 8 - id
// 1 - количество
```

Вопрос. Можно ли через JS ( есть функционал смены количество) менять второй аргумент функции без того что бы трогать первый

Answer (score 0):

Есть возможность удалять году и заново ее создавать, но вариант крайне несурсоемкий, так что его лучше не использовать. Возможно имеет смысл отслеживать количество по какой то внутренней переменной ? Не передавать его как аргумент функции а хранить в глобальном объекте с возможностью добавления для новых товаров.

Comment: Да, отличная идея, передал парамеры через переменную